# how to transfer money from mobile wallet to bitcoin wallet

Tags: transactions, wallet, e-wallet, mobile

is there any way to transfer money(INR,in this case) from a mobile wallet(like Paytm,mobikwik,etc) to any bitcoin wallet(zebpay,xapo,unocoin,etc).
if not...is there any other ways to do this kind of stuff..?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use https://btcxindia.com/ to transfer INR from your bank account/credit card to BTC.